# EME with Clear key is not working with Pre-Signed URL of an encrypted audio file stored in S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, streaming, html5-audio, eme

I have implemented EME using clear key, following practical guide at:
https://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/eme/basics/

I have encrypted an audio using webm-encrypt npm package, by providing it a key and webm audio file. Same key I'm using in my clear key code to decrypt the audio. It works fine when I use the encrypted audio file locally, setting the src as:

```
audio.src = './encrypted.webm'
```

on the other hand I'm storing the same encrypted file in s3. Problem is, when I points the audio src to my server api which in turns redirect to pre-signed s3 url of encrypted audio file, audio is not playing and I see following error in console:

**Failed to generate a license request TypeError: Failed to execute 'generateRequest' on 'MediaKeySession': The initDataType parameter is empty.**

audio element is not null and encrypted event is also fired, but both event.initData and event.initDataType are empty. Not sure what I'm missing here.

**main.js**

```
    "use strict";

var KEY = new Uint8Array([
  0xeb,0xdd,0x62,0xf1,0x68,0x14,0xd2,0x7b,
  0x68,0xef,0x12,0x2a,0xfc,0xe4,0xae,0x3c,
]);

var config = [
  {
    initDataTypes: ["webm"],
    videoCapabilities: [
      {
        contentType: 'video/webm; codecs="vp8"',
      },
    ],
    audioCapabilities: [
      { contentType: 'audio/webm; codecs="opus"' },
      { contentType: 'audio/webm; codecs="vorbis"' },
    ],
  },
];

var audio = document.querySelector("audio");

audio.addEventListener("encrypted", handleEncrypted, false);

createMediaKeys().then(() => {
    //src points to server api
  audio.src = "/api/audio?file=encrypted1.webm";
});

function createMediaKeys() {
  return navigator
    .requestMediaKeySystemAccess("org.w3.clearkey", config)
    .then((keySystemAccess) => {
      return keySystemAccess.createMediaKeys();
    })
    .then((mediaKeys) => {
      return audio.setMediaKeys(mediaKeys);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("Failed to set up MediaKeys", error);
    });
}

function handleEncrypted(event) {
  var session = audio.mediaKeys.createSession();
  session.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
  // error occurs at this line
  session
    .generateRequest(event.initDataType, event.initData)
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("Failed to generate a license request", error);
    });
}

function handleMessage(event) {
  var license = generateLicense(event.message);
  var session = event.target;
  session.update(license).catch(function (error) {
    console.error("Failed to update the session", error);
  });
}

function toBase64(u8arr) {
  return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, u8arr))
    .replace(/\+/g, "-")
    .replace(/\//g, "_")
    .replace(/=*$/, "");
}

function generateLicense(message) {
  var request = JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode(message));
  console.assert(request.kids.length === 1);

  var keyObj = {
    kty: "oct",
    alg: "A128KW",
    kid: request.kids[0],
    k: toBase64(KEY),
  };
  return new TextEncoder().encode(
    JSON.stringify({
      keys: [keyObj],
    })
  );
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>EME with Clear Key</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="audio-player">
        <audio controls>
            <p>This browser does not support the audio element.</p>
        </audio>
    </div>

    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**server.js**

```
app.get("/api/audio", (req, res) => {
  
  const params = {
    Bucket: "test",
    Key: req.query.file,
  };
  const url = AWSS3.getSignedUrl("getObject", params);
  res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=0");

  return res.redirect(302, url);
});
```